# Parameterize JSON POST request for testing REST Web services with SOAPUI

Tags: json, rest, post, soapui

I am testing REST web services with SOAPUI. I am trying to parameterize POST JSON requests. So i created a file called 'JSON.request' and attached it under Request (refer attached screenshot).

[image: Image description]

When my file contains one JSON request, it works fine. For e.g.

```
     { "operation": "PayTxn.Account,CanLogin", "sessionid": 0, "parms": [{"UserName":
     "abcd", "Password": "password"}] }'
```

but when there is more than one request, i am having issues (separated by a `;`)

```
    { "operation": "PayTxn.Account,CanLogin", "sessionid": 0, "parms": [{"UserName": 
    "abcd", "Password": "password"}] };{ "operation": "PayTxn.Misc,GetCountryCodes", 
    "sessionid": 0}
```

In the properties for the request, I specified the value of Multi-Value Delimeter as `;`

In the log I am getting the below error:

```
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3486)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parse(Locale.java:712)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:696)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:683)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject$Factory.parse(XmlObject.java:633)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.createXmlObject(XmlUtils.java:217)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.panels.request.inspectors.schema.InferredSchemaInspector.afterSubmit(InferredSchemaInspector.java:131) 
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:157) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Unexpected element: CDATA 
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038) 
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723) 
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3454) ... 14 more
```

So, please let me know how to fix it. Also, for parameterizing SOAP web services i have always used DataSource and DataSource Loop but i think to parameterize JSON POST requests, i will have to follow the above approach.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your DTO object